# how to convert input list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I know i can convert list of tuples to dict like that

```
list_of_tuples = [("k", 167), ("z", 179), ("u", 179), ("m", 267), ("a", 445), ("l", 134)]
new_dict = {}
new=dict{list_of_tuples}
print(new)
#{'k': 167, 'z': 179, 'u': 179, 'm': 267, 'a': 445, 'l': 134}
```

But what to do when i got user INPUTS this
`[("k", 167), ("z", 179), ("u", 179), ("m", 267), ("a", 445), ("l", 134)]` as string

What User unputs in line as string

```
([("k", 167), ("z", 179), ("u", 179), ("m", 267), ("a", 445), ("l", 134)])
```

i tried with Json to convert to dict but couldn't because its list of tuples

Comment: From a user input you can only get a string never a list of tuples.

Comment: You might want to clarify if you receive a single string like `'[("k", 167), ("z", 179), ("u", 179), ("m", 267), ("a", 445), ("l", 134)]'` or what you have in the question.

Comment: yes user input this one [("k", 167), ("z", 179), ("u", 179), ("m", 267), ("a", 445), ("l", 134)] as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert the string to a list and then you can do dictionary comprehension like this:

```py
import ast
my_list = ast.literal_eval("[("k", 167), ("z", 179), ("u", 179), ("m", 267), ("a", 445), ("l", 134)]")

d = {k:v for k,v in my_list}
```

Comment: Here ure giving list in code itself you need to get list form user as input

Comment: When I posted the answer this was not clear from the question. However, to convert string to list look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list

Comment: thanks i need to read ast module

Comment: Do i understand it right with ast module it can convert inputted Lists sets tuples to lists sets tuples if they have right brackets in input?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to replace `(`, `,` inside tuple, and `)` in the string with `{`, `:` and `}` respectively.

```
>>> i = '[("k", 167), ("z", 179), ("u", 179), ("m", 267), ("a", 445), ("l", 134)]'
>>> j = re.sub(r'\(("\w"), (d+)\)', r'{\1:\2}', i)
>>> d = json.loads(j)
>>> d
[{'k': 167}, {'z': 179}, {'u': 179}, {'m': 267}, {'a': 445}, {'l': 134}]
```

Explanation of `r'\(("\w"), (d+)\)', r'{\1:\2}'`:

- `\(` and `\)` mean "read opening and parenthesis instead of grouping"
- the regular `(` and `)` is a grouping selection which can be used in the replacement with `\n`, where `n` is the position of the group. This is used in the regular expression above twice, so we don't lose the text within double quotes and the number within each tuple
- `\w` corresponds to a sequence of characters that represent a word
- `\d+` corresponds to one or more consecutive digits

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: actually i tried smt like that its good way too can u explain 're.sub(r'\(("\w"), (d+)\)', r'{\1:\2}', i)' if u busy nvm